# Multiple Integration Function

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\mathcal{L}_a\big(f(x)\big)=\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}...\int_{0}^{1}}_{\alpha\ \text{times}}f(x_1...x_\alpha) \ \mathrm dx_1...\mathrm dx_\alpha$$

This is a function/transformation I made while dealing with Multiple Integrations.

There are some trivial but interesting results related to it.
$$\mathcal{L}_a\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\zeta(\alpha)$$

$$\mathcal{L}_a\left(\ln x\right)=-\alpha$$
$$\mathcal{L}_a\left(\ln \left[\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right]\right)=\ln4-2\sum_{r=2}^{\alpha}\frac{\zeta\left(r\right)}{2^{r}}$$
$$\mathcal{L}_a\left(\ln \left[1-x\right]\right)=\sum_{r=2}^{\alpha}\zeta\left(r\right)-\alpha$$

Now if given a function $f(x)$, it should be easy to calculate $\mathcal{L}_a\big(f(x)\big)$.

But then this got me thinking, is there a way we can perform its inverse?

Let us say we want a function $h(x)$ such that:
$$\mathcal{L}_a\big(h(x)\big)=\sin\alpha$$
Is it possible that we can find $h(x)$.
$$h(x)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}_a\big(\sin\alpha\big)$$

This is purely some Recreational Math I was working on.

Comment: Would you be happy with a constant function as your inverse?  Or is this to be true for all $\alpha$’s simultaneously?

Comment: @MichaelBurr But then how would a Constant Function satisfy $\mathcal{L}_a\big(h(x)\big)=\sin\alpha$, it has to be true for all $\alpha$'s.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x_1\dots x_{\alpha})$? $f$ seems to be a single-valued function from what you previously wrote.

Comment: @Zima For Example,
$$\mathcal{L}_3\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-xyz}dxdydz$$
I apologize if the notation is sloppy.

Comment: If $f$ has a taylor expansion around $x=0$ with a radius of convergence of at least 1, $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} L_\alpha(f) = f(0).$  Whatever inverses we are dealing with can't be smooth at the very least, but chances are they are super discontinuous.

I think your question basically boils down to if we can find functions $f_n$ such that the vectors $(L_1(f_n), L_2(f_n), ...)$ span $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$? Even then, showing that this inverse even exists seems to be a hassle.